# Dart: inconsistency in adding days to dates

Tags: dart

When adding one day to `2020-09-18` I get `2020-09-19 00:00:00.000` but when I add 3 days (or more) I get `2020-09-20 23:00:00.000` which first why I got 23 hour? second adding 3 days to 18 is 21 not 20!

What is the problem?

```dart
void main() {
  var dateOne = DateTime.parse('2020-09-18 00:00:00.000');
  var dateTwo = dateOne.add(Duration(days: 1 )); // 2020-09-19 00:00:00.000
  var dateThree = dateOne.add(Duration(days: 3 )); // 2020-09-20 23:00:00.000
  print(dateTwo);
  print(dateThree);
}
```

Comment: Daylight savings time? When adding a day in Dart it means adding 24 hours to a day.

Comment: you were right, converting the base date to Utc fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) since the `add` method does only understand seconds as documented in the API and the `Duration` are therefore converted to seconds before it is used:

> Notice that the duration being added is actually 50 * 24 * 60 * 60 seconds. If the resulting DateTime has a different daylight saving offset than this, then the result won't have the same time-of-day as this, and may not even hit the calendar date 50 days later.
>
> Be careful when working with dates in local time.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/DateTime/add.html

As you also have mentioned yourself, you can get around the issue by using UTC instead.